# Object.defineProperties nested

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Taking the example from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), here is a simple case of `Object.defineProperties`

```
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperties(object1, {
  property1: {
    value: 42,
    writable: true
  },
  property2: {}
});
```

What if I wanted to do a nested one, i.e. something like

```
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperties(object1, {
  nested: {
    property1: {
      value: 42,
      writable: true
    },
    property2: {}
  }
});
```

This obviously does not work, but hopefully, it portrays what I want.

Comment: You can use `Object.defineProperty` for this case [Ref MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defineProperties` can only be passed an *existent object* that you want to add properties to, and it will only define properties *directly* on that object. There's no way around defining the parent object ahead of time, in order to call `defineProperties` on a nested property:

```js
const object1 = {nested: {}};

Object.defineProperties(object1.nested, {
  property1: {
    value: 42,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
  },
  property2: {
    enumerable: true
  }
});
console.log(object1);
```

Comment: What if i want to defineProperties on a function.prototype? As in, I want `MyClass.prototype.nested` to get those new methods/fields

Comment: Simply define the `nested` property ahead of time: `MyClass.prototype.nested = {}`, then use `defineProperties`

Comment: So I'm using https://github.com/michaelolof/typescript-mix module, and I'm trying to modify this so that when I use `@use` I can actually define the mixin on a different key, and that I cannot accomplish

Comment: The problem is that the scope is lost when I do this